# require.js modules loaded too late

Tags: javascript, requirejs, amd

I'm using a html5 video and its metadataloaded event gets fired before require.js has loaded the module which needs to catch it, how can I fix that?

I have placed require.js in the html head.

Comment: Can you load the video dynamically, too?

Comment: no, the video is given into html by a php backend

Comment: then you should load the video at the propertime , when all the dependencies are fetched.

Comment: how could i do that? the html is served by the backend which i am trying not to mess with, as i'd like to solve this on the frontend. but if otherwise not possible, then i'll have to.